# C++ looping is not working as expected: My decode function won't work

Tags: c++, encoding, decode, encode, decoding

In C++ I wanted to make an encode and decode function that is like this:

"AB" encoded is 65S66S. The encode function works as expected, but decode function is not working well.

I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string encodedText;
string decodeTemp;
string decodedText;

string encode (string toEncode)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < toEncode.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 10; j < 126; j++)
        {
            char test = j;
            if (test == toEncode[i])
            {
                encodedText += to_string(j) + 'S';
                break;
            };
        };
    };
    return encodedText;
};

string decode (string toDecode)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < toDecode.length(); i++)
    {
        if (toDecode[i] == 'S') {
            char test = stoi(decodeTemp);
            decodedText += to_string(test);
            decodeTemp = "";
            continue;
        } else { decodeTemp += to_string(toDecode[i]); };
    };
    /*
    Comment to try to fix it:
    encodedtext = 65S66S
    6 != S, decodeTemp = 6
    5 != S, decodeTemp = 65
    S == S, decodedText = A
    6 != S, decodeTemp = 6
    6 != S, decodeTemp = 66
    S == S. decodedText = AB
    */
    return decodedText;
};

int main ()
{
    string myString = "AB";
    cout << "Encoded: " << encode(myString) << endl;
    cout << "Decoded: " << decode(encode(myString));
    return 0;
};
```

I expected:

```
Encoded: 65S66S
Decoded: AB
```

I got:

```
Encoded: 65S66S
Decoded: 778778
```

I don't know what went wrong, but it won't work.

Comment: `decodeTemp += to_string(toDecode[i]);` should probably just be `decodeTemp += toDecode[i];`

Comment: Fyi, `decodeTemp += to_string(toDecode[i])` doesn't make a whole lotta sense. `toDecode[i]` is already a character; just append it. no `to` function is needed there.

Comment: similar problem here: `decodedText += to_string(test);`

Comment: and lastly, move your strings that you are returning from your functions out of the global namespace.

Comment: Use your debugger to see what `decodeTemp` has and `to_string(toDecode[i])` will make the binary representation to a string where `'6'` -> `"54"`.

Comment: First, you should get rid of the global variables.  Second, using `std::stringstream` along with `std::getline` removes any need for `if` statements in the `decode()` function.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, find the first point in the execution where the value of a variable or subexpression is not what you expect & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the global variables.
2. Another solution is to use what C++ has to offer in terms of not having to write code to check for `S`, and thus seemlessly process the string.
   The usage of`std::istringstream` and `std::getline` accomplishes this.

The `decode` function will then look like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string decode(std::string toDecode)
{
    std::string decodedText;

    // Create the stream object   
    std::istringstream strm(toDecode);
    std::string sNum;

    // each input "line" is terminated with an 'S'
    while (std::getline(strm, sNum, 'S'))
    {
       // Convert the string to a number that will be the ASCII value
       decodedText += std::stoi(sNum);
    }
    return decodedText;
}
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/ehTfM7onz)

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   decodedText += test;
   ```
2. ```
   decodedText += toDecode[i];
   ```
3. Make `encodedText` local to `encode()`
4. Make `decodedText` and `decodeTemp` local to `decode()`.